# How to check if many lists have the same length

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have many lists of different types and I want to check if all of the present lists have same size. For example:

```
private List<String> list1;
private List<Integer> list2;
private List<Boolean> list3;
private List<Integer> list4;
private List<String> list5;
private List<String> list6;
private List<String> list7;
private List<String> list8;
private List<String> list9;
private List<String> list10;
```

Of course I can put all this lists in one list (`List<List<T>> lists`) and then check the same size using stream. For example:

```
boolean isSameLength = lists.stream()
  .skip(1)
  .allMatch(l -> l.size() == myList.get(0).size());
```

But I don't want to create a separate list to store other lists. Is there any other way to check the same size of them if we know that the list of lists can be dynamic (I mean we can have N lists)?

Comment: How do you define a dynamic amount of lists without putting them into some collection?

Comment: What do you mean with "any other way"? If not putting inside a list of lists, how could you iterate over them?

Comment: You will have to enumerate all of them in some way, be it `List.of(...)` or `Stream.of(...)`, does not matter. Overall, though, this looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) where creating a class to hold all the possible attributes is maybe a way to go? Try to zoom out for a second and look at the bigger picture, can you maybe refactor the whole logic into something else that would then compose nicely?

Comment: The fact that you have 10 lists of simple values, and want to check if they are the same size, means that you are using parallel arrays, which is an anti-pattern. Your data should be a single list of objects that have 10 fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one way using reflection:

```
class MyCls { // class that contains "dynamic" lists
  private List<String> list1;
  private List<Integer> list2;
}

MyCls cls = new MyCls();

List<List> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Field field : MyCls.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
  Object f = field.get(cls);
  if (f instanceof List) {
    list.add((List) f);
  }
}
// remember to check for list size
if(list.stream()
    .allMatch(l -> list.get(0).size() == l.size())) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Oh! Nasty and nice, I cannot decide whether to upvote or not :). This approach is in general probably not something you would want to do in real life. But it does solve the problem asked by OP.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```java
IntSummaryStatistics stats = Stream.<List<?>>of(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5,
                                                list6, list7, list8, list9, list10)
        .mapToInt(List::size)
        .summaryStatistics();
boolean isSameLength = (stats.getMin() == stats.getMax());
```